# How do I abort a running query in the MongoDB shell?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I can't believe I have to ask this, but how do I stop a query I just ran, which is now running, and will obviously take a very long time to complete in the Mongo shell? `Control+C` appears to crash the shell, and spits out a ton of errors. The silly solutions suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10953034/how-do-i-abort-a-query-in-mongo-javascript-shell) of course do not do anything. I understand that I could like open up another terminal tab and 
run `db.currentOp()`, find the operation ID, and then run `db.killOp()`, but I can't believe that's the only solution. I must be missing something obvious.

Comment: hmm ctrl+c breaking console sounds bad, that's what I normally use

Comment: Plus, Ctrl+C does _not_ necessarily kill the op. Bottom line: Besides killOp, the only reliable way to stop an operation is to stop the cluster.

Comment: Use `db.currentOp()` and then `db.killOp()`. Ctrl-c and that other question have nothing to do with cancelling an operation that is already running on the database.

Comment: @wdberkeley So MongoDB does not kill the op when it detects a SIGTERM? Sounds counter-intuitive to me

Comment: It's not just counter-intuitive, it's an extremely poor UI decision on the part of the Mongo team. Obviously I must be using Mongo "wrong", because generally when I run a query, and realize in a few seconds that the query will take far longer than it should (perhaps an index was forgotten; perhaps I'm testing a complicated compound index, perhaps I made a typo and it's now searching for some nonexistent unindexed field) **I want to kill the query and return to my Mongo shell**. It is bizarre to me that Mongo doesn't do this on Control-C like every other mainstream database software and shell.

Comment: Control+D from this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10953034/how-do-i-abort-a-query-in-mongo-javascript-shell

Comment: @collisionTwo, see my answer please

Comment: @collisionTwo This question has been answered. Please, accept an answer as the correct one, so everyone can see them :)

Answer (score 60):

Based on Alex's answer.

1. Query current running operations:

   ```
   db.currentOp()
   ```

[image: Mongo currentOp Response]

2. Kill the operation based on opid

   ```
   db.killOp(30318806)
   ```

Comment: Works great at mongodb 3.4

Comment: doesn't work for a sharded cluster. I get this error : "op had the wrong type. Expected string, found double"

Comment: Why does it work this way? I have to open a new terminal window or use screen to create a new session.. authenticate to the admin user only.. run db.corruentOp(), then copy and paste the opid.. then run db.killOp and paste the opid. Around a full minute vs just hitting CTRL+ C in less than a fraction of a second like I can in other database CLIs.

Answer (score 12):

According to Mongo [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/tutorial/terminate-running-operations/), you should:

1. Obtain the current operation ID via `db.currentOp()`
2. Kill opp via `db.killOp()`

Good example script can be found [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/60030).

Answer (score 5):

For sharded cluster:

1. `db.currentOp()`
2. `db.killOp("shard_id:opid")`

For example:

```
db.killOp("shard0000:3134616")
```