# Cancel Search using Command Prompt in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I'm using a PC and I'm learning how to use Mongo. I have my Command Prompt open and I did two queries with typos.

```
typo1: db.ninjas.find(_id: ObjectId("58ebfea52bba9b052721d178") 
typo2: db.ninjas.fin({_id: ObjectId("58ebfea52bba9b052721d178")})
```

Because of the typos, the search is still being conducted. How do I cancel a search?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I abort a running query in the MongoDB shell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26940616/how-do-i-abort-a-running-query-in-the-mongodb-shell)