# Abort mongo shell command (as a infinite loop) without ending the shell itself

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-shell

I run the following in MongoDB shell (version 4.2, as reference):

```
while(true) { db.c.update({_id:1}, {$inc: {n: 1}}) }
```

I want to break the while loop, but without ending the MongoDB shell. If I use `Ctrl+C` the loop ends, but also the `mongo` process (like if I have done `exit`).

Looking to [mongo shell documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongo-shell/) I found `Ctrl+G` as "abort" but it's not working (it seems to do nothing).

Is possible to do what I'm trying? What the purpose of `Ctrl+G`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Not possible. You are confusing aborting the MongoDB operation with JS execution.

`Ctrl + G` aborts **individual** CRUD operation, not `while(true){...}`

Let's see this example:

```
db.collection.find({$where:"this.foo==1"});print("1");db.collection.find({$where:"this.foo==1"});print("2");
> executing...
> Ctrl + G
> 1
> executing...
> Ctrl + G
> 2
```

Answer (score 1):

We shouldn't confuse the JS execution with aborting the shell.

To abort a JS query within MongoDB shell, take a look at this thread: [How do I abort a query in mongo JavaScript shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10953034/how-do-i-abort-a-query-in-mongo-javascript-shell).

On the programming side, you can use `break` to cause JS loop interruption, without affecting the shell.

For example, to have just 10 repetitions of your snipper, every 2 seconds, you can do something like this...

```js
var i=1;
while(true) {
    db.c.update({_id:1}, {$inc: {n: 1}});
    if(i>10) {
        break;
    }
    sleep(2000);
    i++;
}
```

Also, the MongoDB shell supports `try`/`catch` blocks, as well as a [sleep()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/sleep) method. All you need is there, I believe :-).